# Is there a github markdown language identifier for Objective C code?

Tags: objective-c, github, markdown

In the official [github flavored markdown docs](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) they show how we can use fences to mark code blocks, and optionally we can supply a language identifier, such as

````
```ruby
require 'redcarpet'
markdown = Redcarpet.new("Hello World!")
puts markdown.to_html
```
````

Is there a language identifier for Objective C? I've searched and cannot find a reference.

Furthermore, is there a list of all supported language identifiers that can be used in github markdown?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The identifier is `objective-c`.

Here you can find a full list:
http://coapp.org/reference/garrett-flavored-markdown.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Using `objective-c` provides almost no syntax highlighting, which is why I wanted it. But thanks to your list I discovered `smalltalk`, which provides for very colorful Objective C code in github :)

Comment: This site is on github: https://github.com/coapp/coapp.org/blob/master/src/dynamic/reference/garrett-flavored-markdown.html.md

Answer (score 23):

The identifier is

```
objc
```

See this example here where the author gets code highlighting to work: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dchohfi/KeyValueObjectMapping/master/README.md

Here is another example as well: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/objective-c-style-guide/master/README.md

Comment: It seems to be 'objective-c'.

Comment: Using the redcarpet markdown parser, this gave me the best results.  I found `objective-c` to provide little to no highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

If you the other solutions from other do not work, please try **objectivec** that works in highlight.js and prism.js